# Как сохранять условия, заданные пользователем, в базу данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Возникла сложность с моим рабочим проектом: **есть тест с нескольким количеством блоков в нем**. Непосредственно по блокам есть разное количество вопросов и ответов на них. **Суть в том, что на этапе создания какого-либо теста, нужно определить условие, которое будет регламентировать движение по тесту** (сначала один блок, потом второй или третий в зависимости от данных ответов в первом блоке)

Пример:
*"Тест 1" делится на 3 блока: Блок "А", Блок "Б" и Блок "В". В Блок "А" входит 10 вопросов и в зависимости от результата пройденного Блока "А" система будет решать по заданным условиям, какой надо давать блок: Блок "Б" **или** Блок "В".*

**Подскажите, каким образом отобразить это в базе данных? Какую таблицу можно создать, чтобы сохранять туда условия заданные пользователем?**

Comment: Самое простое что приходит в голову система баллов, в зависимости от их количества — длина перехода к следующему тесту, но не ясно из описания задачи насколько это подходит.

Comment: А почему именно в БД? Мне кажется это работа для серверного ЯП (клиенсткого, если пофиг до честности пользователя). В частоности придётся использовать скорее всего паттерн "цепочка обязанностей" ну или если натянуть сову на глобус,то "состояние"

Comment: в какой среде выполняется ваш тест? Если браузер, то снабдите каждый тест доп. js-скриптом, который знает как этот тест проходить.

Comment: потом ведь еще потребуется какие нибудь результаты теста получить, и у кажддого теста будет своя логика подсчетов

Comment: @DaniilLoban верно, каждый вопрос имеет баллы, но есть типы тестов, которые могут переходит к следующему блоку, если на последний вопрос блока дан определенный ответ. Прошу прощения не указал в условиях.

Comment: @teran когда пользователь создает тест, ему на выбор должны предлагаться условия, о которых я написал выше. Перенести это на клиентскую часть можно, но для начала надо выяснить, как это сохранить в БД, чтобы знать, как именно должен проходится тест.

Comment: @Rise *"но для начала надо выяснить, как это сохранить в БД"* --- а чего тут думать? обычная таблица с тестом с ссылкой на таблицу с его блоками...ну и таблицы с оценками и там "прошёл"/"не прошёл"...... то, что описано в вопросе в виде *"в зависимости от результата пройденного Блока "А" система будет решать по заданным условиям, какой надо давать блок: Блок "Б" или Блок "В"."*  никаким образом к проектированию БД вообще не относится. Это банальная логика в коде.... а структура БД простейшая: таблица тест и таблицы его составляющие

Comment: Ну максимум можно в каком-то столбце хранить зависимость в виде строчки A.B.D или A.D.F.C. Хотя я всё же считаю это должно быть в логике кода написано... или конфигах, но не в БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в зависимости от результата пройденного Блока "А" система будет решать по заданным условиям, какой надо давать блок: Блок "Б" или Блок "В".

Если результат прохождения блока формализуется в единое значение-результат, по которому принимается решение, то обычная таблица (пройденный блок - пороговый результат - переход к блоку). Например:

```
CREATE TABLE transition (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    completed_block INT,
    criteria_from INT,
    criteria_till INT,
    next_block INT
    );

INSERT INTO transition VALUES 
(1, 1, 0, 80, 2),   -- если в блоке 1 набрано от 0 до 80 баллов - перейти к блоку 2
(2, 1, 81, 100, 3), -- если в блоке 1 набрано от 81 до 100 баллов - перейти к блоку 3
(3, 2, 0, 80, -1),  -- если в блоке 2 набрано от 0 до 80 баллов - завершить тест
(4, 2, 81, 100, 3), -- если в блоке 2 набрано от 81 до 100 баллов - перейти к блоку 3
(5, 3, 0, 100, -1); -- если в блоке 3 набрано от 0 до 100 баллов - завершить тест
```

Ну и соответственно

```
SELECT COALESCE(next_block, -1)  -- получить номер блока, к которому перейти
                                 -- если запись не найдена, завершить тест
FROM transition 
WHERE completed_block = @completed_block 
AND @points_received BETWEEN criteria_from AND criteria_till;
```

При заполнении необходимо следить за неразрывностью цепочек прохождения тестов и отсутствием петель. Впрочем, тестировать можно и запросом, причём каждый раз, когда выполняется корректировка таблицы.